# How to get first character from firstName and lastName from Database and assign to object?

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to this. I am getting data from database and storing each tuple in the following way to form a list:

```
var dataFromDB = (
    from to in _context.Time
    join user in _context.Users
    on to.UserId equals user.Id
    select new Events
    {
        userId = user.Id,
        title = user.FirstName[0] + " " + user.LastName[0],
        ...
    }).ToList();
```

I want `title` to have the initials from `FirstName` and `LastName` where `FirstName` and `LastName` are coming from the `Users` table. Example, if the `FirstName` is `John` and `LastName` is `Doe`, then I want `title` to have `JD`.

`Events` class is in the following way:

```
public class CalendarEvents
{
    public string userId { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }               
    ...
}
```

**Edit 1.0**

On running the code, I am getting the following exception:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code.
>
> Additional information: Value cannot be null.

**Edit 2.0**

`FirstName` and `LastName` is in the following way:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter first name")]
[Display(Name = "First Name")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter last name")]
[Display(Name = "Last Name")]
public string LastName { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the first initial and second initial I would suggest:

```
title = user.FirstName.FirstOrDefault().ToString()
    + user.LastName.FirstOrDefault().ToString(),
```

Since, `user.FirstName.FirstOrDefault()` returns the first character from the `FirstName`.